# Как запустит код в VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Хочу начать изучать питон но уже запнулся на стадии запуска кода, извините за тупой вопрос что это значит, в чем проблема и как решить
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это значит запустить скрипт -_-

Comment: Может быть он пустой? Сохраните, запустите заново. Такое ощущение, что изменения не сохранены, судя по кружку около имени файла)

Comment: Благодарю, оказывается нужно было и вправду просто сохранить, еще раз сорян за глупый вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Сохранить файл надо
Если не помогло то ctrl-shift-p
Python select Interpreter и выбирай питон